# How to import DWG file from CorelDraw to MapInfo project?

Tags: wms, mapinfo, georeferencing, dwg, tab

I have to make polygons of some protected areas in MapInfo. I have the WMS with the protected areas loaded into mapinfo but making polygons from the WMS will take me years.

So I took the following steps: 
-saved the window (.jpg) with polygons from WMS that I was interested in, 
-imported the .jpg in CorelDraw, 
-traced the bitmap so I had only vectorized contour of the polygons
-exported it as .dwg file
-created .tab file from .dwg file in MapInfo Universal Translator

And at this point I have a problem. When I open the new .tab file based on CorelWork in MapInfo with georeferenced map or the WMS with protected areas, the new .tab and my polygons are in totally different place and much smaller (few meters comparing to kilometres) than original polygons in WMS. Corel works in cm/in/mm etc. and my project in mapinfo has hundreds of km.

Can you help me fit polygons from .tab based on Corel to .tab with proper scale and projection? Sorry if I'm chaotic. Corel and MapInfo are the only programs I can use. I have no access to AutoCad and so on.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Our protocols can take a little getting used to but in a moment you will see me remove your name from the body of the Question. This is because the help says: "Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers. 

Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!
"

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool named "Register Vector" that comes with MapInfo. 
You need to enable it first in Tools/Tools Manager...  and then it will show up in Tools menu.

This utility allows you to copy a table of vector objects (regions, polylines, points, etc.) from one location to another, by specifying target locations for three points in the original table. In the process the vector table is transformed, skewed, scaled and rotated to display properly.

Examples would be a DXF or ESRI shape file that was imported with wrong projection or no projection at all - which is exactly your case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to manually georeference your CorelDraw drawing. See [this guide](http://www.slideshare.net/nasirajk/map-info-ppt) on methodology to accomplish this.

One generality with georeferencing that may serve you well is this: In general, the more control points you add, the more accurate the georeference. Continue adding control points like in the link provided until your overlay is accurate enough to your standards.

Comment: This guide is for georeferencing a RASTER in MapInfo, but his problem is with opening non-georeferenced VECTOR files. He need to move objects in DWG file to right position, not a raster.

Comment: As already mentioned this presentation covers how to register a raster file and not a vector file. You could however create your own question regarding registering raster files and then add your own answer to it. Nice presentation!